# WEB API return all objects instead of one

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I want to expose a list of services from my DB or just return one service detail via Web API with my `EF DBmodel` . I used VS2012 Web API scaffolding, quite easy so far and it works and return the list of services in `JSON` when I hit the URL`(.../api/Services)`.  The problem is that when I want to obtain just one service URL`(.../api/Services/1)`, I still obtain the full list of all services although when I trace it seems to return only a count of 1 object.

What happening here?

Here are the 2 controller actions.

**ps:** I also tried using a `.Where()` instead of `.Find()` but the result is the same in both cases.

```
    // GET api/Services
    public IEnumerable<service> Getservices()
    {
        var services = db.services.Include(s => s.Category).Include(s => s.Country).Include(s => s.StateProvince).Include(s => s.Territory);
        return services.AsEnumerable();

    }
    // GET api/Services/5
    public service Getservice(int id)
    {
        service service = db.services.Find(id);          
        if (service == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return service;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try handling it as: `var service = db.services.Single(s => s.Id == id)`

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your database has a single item for your query or not.

If you are querying by primary key then 
`db.services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id)` should do.

You will need to handle the exception if you are querying on some field which may give back more than one result.

The variant of filtering (`Single, SingleOrDefault, First, FirstOrDefault`) that you use will depend upon the exact semantics of the code.

Comment: Thnaks raina & Chris. I tried what you proposed but I still obtain the full list even if I select only one record.

Comment: Thnaks raina & Chris. I tried what you proposed but I still obtain the full list even if I select only one record. What is weird is that when I trace step by step and look at the content of service (return service;) at the moment I return it contains only one record. but it renders all Json records in my web page.  I never experienced this when I did a standard MVC action returning a JsonResult. It must be related to the fact that service has category + country + state external keys because if I do the same scaffolding web API controller on the table categories it works.

Comment: OK Fixed.. A bit related to my last remarks it was because a side effect to reach the whole object graph because it is by default LazyLoading.  I turned it off in my xxModel.Context.cs file with this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; and it now just return the record I want.